# reCAPTCHA проверка на Python

Tags: python

Как связать форму с проверкой reCAPTCHA?

```
mail = Mail(app);
@app.route('/order', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_orders():
    form = OrderForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        order = Order()
        order.name = form.name.data
        order.email = form.email.data
        order.organization_name = form.organization_name.data
        order.contact_phone = form.contact_phone.data
        order.text = form.text.data
        db.session.merge(order)

        @copy_current_request_context
        def send_message(order):
            msg = Message("Новый заказ на site.ru",
                          sender=("site", "mail@mail.ru"),
                          recipients=["mail@mail.ru"])
            msg.body = u"Новый заказ на mail.su: "
            mail.send(msg)
        sender = threading.Thread(name='mail_sender', target=send_message,
        args=(order,))
        sender.start()

        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('order.html', form=OrderForm(), thanx=True)
    return render_template('order.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Приведённый вами код не относится к Django.

Comment: Похоже на flask